# What playtest or silver-bordered cards were eventually tweaked and printed in black border?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The playtest card [Boneyard Aberration](https://scryfall.com/card/j21/14/boneyard-aberration) is being printed digitally in Jumpstart Horizons. It's a digital-only black bordered equivalent to the playtest card [Bone Rattler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bone%20Rattler) with some minor rebalancing.

Similarly, the silver-bordered [Giant Fan](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Giant%20Fan) was later reprinted in black border as [Power Conduit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Power%20Conduit) with some minor rules tweaking and rebalancing.

What other playtest cards from the Mystery Booster set or silver-bordered cards from the Unsets were later printed (possibly with balance or rules tweaks) in a black bordered set?

Answer (score 7):

[The Cheese Stands Alone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Cheese%20Stands%20Alone) → [Barren Glory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Barren%20Glory)

[Hungry Hungry Heifer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hungry%20Hungry%20Heifer) ≈ [Chisei, Heart of Oceans](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Chisei%2C%20Heart%20of%20Oceans)

[Rocket-Powered Turbo Slug](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rocket-Powered%20Turbo%20Slug) ≈ [Pact cycle](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22next+upkeep%22+o%3A%22.+If+you+don%27t%2C+you+lose+the+game.%22)

[The Ultimate Nightmare of Wizards of the Coast® Customer Service](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Ultimate%20Nightmare%20of%20Wizards%20of%20the%20Coast%C2%AE%20Customer%20Service) ≈ [Comet Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Comet%20Storm)

[Krark's Other Thumb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Krark%27s%20Other%20Thumb) ≈ [Barbarian Class](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Barbarian%20Class), [Pixie Guide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pixie%20Guide)

[Assquatch](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Assquatch) ≈ [Coercive Recruiter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coercive%20Recruiter)

[Super-Duper Death Ray](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Super-Duper%20Death%20Ray) → [Flame Spill](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flame%20Spill)

[Enchantmentize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Enchantmentize) → [One with the Stars](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=One%20with%20the%20Stars)

[B.F.M.](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=B.F.M.) (Big Furry Monster) ≈ [Meld mechanic](https://scryfall.com/search?q=layout:meld)

[Host/Augment](https://scryfall.com/search?q=layout:host+or+layout:augment) ≈ [Mutate](https://scryfall.com/search?q=kw:mutate)

Comment: I'm not sure I would count the last one, as the +1.5/+1.5 lord boost is as least as important to the card as the threaten trigger, and Recruiter doesn't have that

Comment: @ArcanistLupus I agree with that assessment - to steal a symbol from math, maybe we could use the ⫊ symbol to show that a subset of the card is approximately equal to it?

Comment: @toroid maybe, but in this case it feels misleading, because the equal portion was entirely black border legal when printed, and the part that was left out was the silverbordered component

Comment: @Arcanist Ah, I agree with that

Answer (score 1):

There are probably quite a few more that I can't think of right now, so I've marked this as a Community Wiki answer.

- [_____](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74252) → [Spy Kit](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416836)
- [Angelic Rocket](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439528) → [Meteor Golem](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=532597)

Comment: Angelic Rocket to Meteor Golem doesn't really fit here. It's mechanically similar, but all of the parts that are the same already existed in black border at the time Angelic Rocket was printed, just not with that exact wording. The only silver bordered part of Angelic Rocket was the host/augment mechanic, and Meteor Golem doesn't have that.

Comment: The asker did not specify that they were looking  for new mechanics- just balance or rules tweaks. @toroid - what do you think please?